# Windows 10 Mobile Continuum support?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, continuum

So, on Windows 10 tablets you will be able to connect a keyboard and it will suggest switching to the full windows interface. This feature is called continuum. Now, a similar thing is possible with Ubuntu Touch, however with Ubuntu Touch this even works when connecting a monitor + keyboard to a phone giving a full desktop experience from a phone. As far as I have been able to find continuum is not supported on Windows 10 Mobile though I have not been able to find any sources explicitly saying so, so my question is whether this really is not possible and if so why not? As it seems to be quite a major feature for the unified experience they seem to target.

Do note, I am not looking for (baseless) speculation, so please, do back your answer up with actual sources.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you expect continuum to look like on the phone? As you're saying the only thing it does on the PC is make apps fullscreen - which they are on the phone anymay.

Comment: @thomas I would expect that when you connect a screen, mouse and keyboard that you would get windows again. Just like with windows tablets or Ubuntu touch tablets and phones.

Comment: this will not work as (though Microsoft is marketing it that way) Windows 10 for desktop and Windows 10 for phones are not exactely the same. they do share the same core and both can run universal apps, but thats basically it. phones also can't run "legacy" apps and there's no desktop either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft just announced Continuum for Windows Phone 10 during the Build keynote...so I guess you have your answer.  :-)
http://www.engadget.com/2015/04/29/continuum-windows-10-phone/
http://www.buildwindows.com/

Comment: Careful. It has been announced. However none of the current phones has the hardware needed to sustain this feature (Dual-screen, etc...)

Comment: Good point babttz.  None of the existing hardware will be able to support it due to newer hardware being required that supports HDMI-out.

Answer (score 3):

From: [Windows Help - Set up Continuum for phones](https://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/getstarted-set-up-continuum-mobile)

> #### Set up Continuum for phones
>
> How you set up Continuum for phones depends on what type of hardware you’ve got. Here's what you'll need to get started.
>
> [image: Screenshot]
>  <sup>(Click image to see animation)</sup>
>
> - A TV or monitor with HDMI input.
> - A Windows 10 Mobile phone that’s compatible with Continuum for phones.
> - A compatible accessory for connecting your phone to your TV or monitor.
> - A power outlet to plug in your dock or adapter.
>
> There are two types of accessories you can use to connect: wired docks that your phone plugs into, and Miracast adapters that your phone can connect to wirelessly.

---

Visit the above link for step-by-step instructions for connecting a Windows 10 Mobile phone that’s compatible with Continuum for phones to a TV or monitor.